# Create a shape with libvips ruby

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, imagick, mogrify, vips

How can I convert a picture with any color and form to its shape? As an example I attached an input image and desired output. I need to make this conversion with ruby and ruby-vips gem. Generally speaking, I need to fill anything that is not alpha channel with single color.

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [use `[ ]` to get bands](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-vips/Vips/Image#[]-instance_method) out of an image. Your image is RGBA, so 0, 1 and 2 are R, G and B, and 3 is A.

```rb
alpha = image[3]
```

[image: alpha channel of sample image]

You can use ranges as well, so eg.:

```rb
rgb = image[0..2]
```

Gets the first three bands. `bandsplit` breaks an image into an array of one-band images:

```rb
r, g, b, a = image.bandsplit
```

The alpha has 0 for transparent and 255 for solid, and it sounds like you'd prefer the inverse of that. Therefore:

```rb
mask = image[3].invert
```